# split large dataset into subsets based on columns

Tags: perl, awk

I have a very large dataset (20000x97) that I want to split into multiple subsets where column 1 should be included in every subset then each of the remaining columns should be in separate files together with column 1. The output should be tab-separated. Please see example below.

Mydata (example):

```
Seq                     124R 239G 361R 267G
TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCTGTTG 27  15  15  52
CACCCGTAGAACCGACCTT 58  32  44  69
TCAAGTAATCCAGGATAGGC    4   4   6   15
TTTGGCAATGGTAGAACTCACACTGGTGAGGT    7   45  0   33
CACCCGTAGAACCGACCTTGC   488 740 834 1784
CTGAGACCTCTGGGTTCTGAGCT 20  11  4   33
CCCATAAAGTAGAAAGCAC 47  53  56  235
TACCCATTGCATATCGGAGTTGT 174 257 206 333
```

I want to split the file into subfiles like this:

file1:

```
Seq                     124G
TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCTGTTG 27
CACCCGTAGAACCGACCTT 58
TCAAGTAATCCAGGATAGGC    4
TTTGGCAATGGTAGAACTCACACTGGTGAGGT    7
CACCCGTAGAACCGACCTTGC   488
CTGAGACCTCTGGGTTCTGAGCT 20
CCCATAAAGTAGAAAGCAC 47
TACCCATTGCATATCGGAGTTGT 174
```

file2:

```
Seq                     239G
TGAGGTAGTAGTTTGTGCTGTTG 15
CACCCGTAGAACCGACCTT 32
TCAAGTAATCCAGGATAGGC    4
TTTGGCAATGGTAGAACTCACACTGGTGAGGT    45
CACCCGTAGAACCGACCTTGC   740
CTGAGACCTCTGGGTTCTGAGCT 11
CCCATAAAGTAGAAAGCAC 53
TACCCATTGCATATCGGAGTTGT 257
```

file3...

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ( $col, @fhs );

# Get header's columns
my @header = split ' ', <>;

# open cols-1 files for appending (array of file handles); write their headers
for $col ( 1 .. $#header ) {
    open $fhs[$col], '>>', "file$col.txt"
      or die "Unable to open file$col.txt: $!";

    print { $fhs[$col] } "$header[0]\t$header[$col]\n";
}

# split each record into fields; append fields as new records to their files
while (<>) {
    my @record = split;

    for $col ( 1 .. $#header ) {
        print { $fhs[$col] } "$record[0]\t$record[$col]\n";
    }
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl dataFile`

This approach reads only one line at a time from your dataset, so there should be no problem processing "a very large dataset."

Answer (score 1):

Have you got the answer if not : try this below

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open FH, "<input.txt";
my @ARR = <FH>;
my (@MAIN, @one, @two, @thr, @fou);
foreach (@ARR)
{
     push (@MAIN, $1), push (@one, $2),push (@two, $3),push (@thr, $4),push (@fou, $5), if($_ =~ /(\S+)\s+?(\S+)\s+?(\S+)\s+?(\S+)\s+?(\S+)/);
}
foreach (1..4)
{
    open FH, ">FILE$_".".txt";
    my @ARR;
    for(my $i = 0;$i<@MAIN;$i++)
    {
        if($_ == 1){@ARR = @one;}
        if($_ == 2){@ARR = @two;}
        if($_ == 3){@ARR = @thr;}
        if($_ == 4){@ARR = @fou;}
        print FH $MAIN[$i],"\t",$ARR[$i],"\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
awk -vOFS="\t" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){ f=sprintf("file_%d.txt",i-1); if(f in F){ print $1,$i >>f }else{ print $1,$i >f; F[f]} close(f) }}' file
```

**Better Readable version**

```
awk -vOFS="\t" '{
       # Loop through fields
       for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)
       { 
            # Filename variable 
            f=sprintf("file_%d.txt",i-1)

            # If filename index exists in array F
            # Append to file if exists
            if(f in F)
            { 
               print $1,$i >>f 
            }
        else{ 
               # write to file
               print $1,$i >f 

               # Array F where key is filename
               F[f]
            } 
            # close file since we do not know how many columns exists 
            # in your original file, to avoid too many open files error
            # we close everytime, and append if filename exists in array F
            close(f) 
       }
    }' file
```

Comment: my file contains 96 columns + row names in column 1. Does this change anything in the script

Comment: `awk -v OFS="\t"` is just to set output separator, I didn't receive any error while testing, what os and version of awk you have ?

Comment: Sorry, it seems to be the missing tab. -vOFS

Comment: Okay, otherwise set it in BEGIN block like this `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{ remaning code }' file` if you are on `mawk` install `gawk`